# SPARQL query in Protege

Tags: sparql, protected, protege

I am trying to query my ontology through the [Protégé](http://protege.stanford.edu/) Tool. But the result I am getting for my queries is "No Match Found".

My SPARQL query is given below.

```
SELECT ?g
WHERE { ?g rdfs:subClassOf "#bomb" . }
```

Please can anyone tel me why am I  getting the result as this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no knowledge whatsoever about SPARQL, but from a quick look at the spec - can it be you query is missing a "PREFIX rdfs: <http:/ /www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>";

Comment: I've changed the tag from "protege4" to "protege". Protege 4 does not support SPARQL queries. So you must be using Protege 3.x, right?

Comment: @Kaarel A few years later, Protégé 4 does include SPARQL query support;  I've added the tag back.

Answer (score 3):

The graph pattern

```
?g rdfs:subClassOf "#bomb" .
```

tries to matche a statement with literal string "`#bomb`". Since the predicate is `rdfs:subClassOf`, you probably want to match a class URI. So, change `"#bomb"` to `<your-full-uri-here>`.

Answer (score 1):

Protege 4 don't have support for SPARQL language.  Now you might use simples queries like that:

Person **that** hasChild **some** **True**

The result is a list of individuals that are father.